# Database error when attempting to add a contribution to a constituent's record

Tags: civicontribute, database

I'm getting an error screen when I try to add a donation to a constituent's record.  I've pasted the error below.  I think it comes down to `Field 'amount_level' doesn't have a default value` for the `civicrm_contribution` table.  Can someone please tell me what the default value is supposed to be?  Or should that field allow null?

Should I report this as a bug?

Thanks,
Richard

```
Error Field Error Value
Type    DB_Error
Code    -1
Message DB Error: unknown error
Mode    16
UserInfo    INSERT INTO `civicrm_contribution` (`contact_id` , `financial_type_id` , `contribution_page_id` , `payment_instrument_id` , `receive_date` , `non_deductible_amount` , `total_amount` , `fee_amount` , `net_amount` , `trxn_id` , `invoice_id` , `currency` , `cancel_date` , `cancel_reason` , `receipt_date` , `thankyou_date` , `source` , `is_pay_later` , `contribution_status_id` , `check_number` , `creditnote_id` , `tax_amount` ) VALUES ( 5536 , 3 , NULL , 4 , 20220614171300 , 0.00 , 1000 , 0 , 1000 , NULL , NULL , 'USD' , NULL , NULL , NULL , 20220615000000 , NULL , 0 , 1 , NULL , NULL , 0 ) [nativecode=1364 ** Field 'amount_level' doesn't have a default value]
DebugInfo   INSERT INTO `civicrm_contribution` (`contact_id` , `financial_type_id` , `contribution_page_id` , `payment_instrument_id` , `receive_date` , `non_deductible_amount` , `total_amount` , `fee_amount` , `net_amount` , `trxn_id` , `invoice_id` , `currency` , `cancel_date` , `cancel_reason` , `receipt_date` , `thankyou_date` , `source` , `is_pay_later` , `contribution_status_id` , `check_number` , `creditnote_id` , `tax_amount` ) VALUES ( 5536 , 3 , NULL , 4 , 20220614171300 , 0.00 , 1000 , 0 , 1000 , NULL , NULL , 'USD' , NULL , NULL , NULL , 20220615000000 , NULL , 0 , 1 , NULL , NULL , 0 ) [nativecode=1364 ** Field 'amount_level' doesn't have a default value]
PEAR_Exception: DB Error: unknown error in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php on line 922
- DB_Error: DB Error: unknown error in unknown on line unknown
Exception trace
#   Function    Location
0   CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler()  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php:922
1   PEAR_Error->__construct()   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB.php:997
2   DB_Error->__construct() /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php:575
3   PEAR::_raiseError() /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php:223
4   PEAR->__call()  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/common.php:1928
5   DB_common->raiseError() /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysqli.php:936
6   DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysqli.php:406
7   DB_mysqli->simpleQuery()    /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/common.php:1234
8   DB_common->query()  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php:2696
9   DB_DataObject->_query() /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php:1245
10  DB_DataObject->insert() /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php:660
11  CRM_Core_DAO->save()    /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php:202
12  CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution::add()  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php:484
13  CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution::create()   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution.php:1786
14  CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution->submit()  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution.php:948
15  CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution->postProcess() /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php:573
16  CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()    /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php:152
17  CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->realPerform() /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php:119
18  CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->perform() /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php:203
19  HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle() /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php:103
20  HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle()   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php:355
21  CRM_Core_Controller->run()  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Page/Tab.php:409
22  CRM_Contribute_Page_Tab->edit() /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Page/Tab.php:465
23  CRM_Contribute_Page_Tab->run()  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:319
24  CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem()  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69
25  CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke()  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36
26  CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke()   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1199
27  CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke() /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:307
28  WP_Hook->apply_filters()    /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:331
29  WP_Hook->do_action()    /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php:476
30  do_action() /var/www/html/wp-admin/admin.php:259
31  {main}   
Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
DB Error: unknown error

Return to home page.
```

Comment: How are you trying to add the data?  Which form?  What version?

Comment: CiviCRM version 5.50.3.  I get the error when I go to Contributions -> New Contrubition